# Rails app working locally but not deploying to Heroku due to new method definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

My rails app is working fine locally.  However, when I deploy it to Heroku it does not work.

Here is the method I defined that is causing the error:

```
def user_booth 
    Booth.find(session[:user_id])
    end
```

Here is the Heroku log error message:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Booth with 'id'=3):
2014-11-10T22:56:32.634375+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2265993391898604291_70174020605760'
2014-11-10T22:56:32.634373+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:41:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___16162113934496826_70174022069520'
2014-11-10T22:56:32.631189+00:00 app[web.1]:   Booth Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "booths".* FROM "booths" WHERE "booths"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
2014-11-10T22:56:32.632475+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 88ms
```

After reading about this problem for others I tried adding an 'attr_accessor' to the model and that did not solve the problem.  I also tried Heroku restart and that also did not help.  I also ran Heroku db:migrate.  None of those solutions worked.  Can anybody toss me another suggestion?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Booth with 'id'=3):
```

does not indicate a problem with your code necessarily, but that something in your application is looking for a Booth with id 3, and your database (probably Heroku Postgres or similar) does not have a `booth` record with `id` of 3.

If I had to guess, I'd say you probably want to find a booth by it's user id, not a booth that has the same id as the user in session (which is what your method is doing).

Something like :

```
Booth.find_by_user(session[:user_id])
```

or similar (my Rails is rusty)

Comment: Thanks, this sounds right.  It says 'find_by_user' is an undefined method but this will lead me in a better direction.